# SSIS XML variable

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a foreach loop wherein there are few execute sql tasks and a script task.  There is a SQL task that generates XML, then a script task to validate it and then a SQL task to save the validated XMl in database.  Now what is happening here is after a few successful XML generation and saving in database, the Execute SQL task fails to save the xml in database, with error that Xml is invalid.  And then I found that the XML being passed to this task to save in database, is truncated.  I have used XML type variable in the task, whereas XMl comes as varchar from other task(as there is no XMl type for SSIS parameters).  I feel this is something related to memory.  Because based on the XML size, sometimes it fails after 10 xml succesfully saved, and if size is less, then maybe after 20-25 xmls.  Some help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since at the first load you were able to extract to the Destination Table. What was the DataType in the Table. Is the data you are trying to extact from XML to a DB Table same the first time you saved and the second time you were not able to load. What is the Difference in Data that you were trying to load? need some information.

Comment: What is the Error message it throws if the load is not Successful ? Just a Xml parsing error or something else too

Comment: No difference in data.  Its a loop that generates XML and stores in database, but after a few XML stored, it gives error while saving because it received truncated xml. Just in the task before this, XML is full and valid.